# Cloth shape key location change

Tags: cloth-simulation

I created cloth sim and it works fine but when I use cloth modifer ''save as shape key'' option my cloth change place. I basicly disable cloth modifer and use shape key but my tshirt changes location or rotation. What causing this what I'm missing can you help me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe share your file (only the shirt) so that someone can check?

Comment: I want to know theory behind this. I dont want to solve it for just only this file. I want to learn than I can fix my all problems about clothing. Do you know why this is happening? I tried to ctrl A apply all transforms maybe it fixes but it didint.

Comment: Don't worry, people that figure out the problem will explain as best as they can, rather than just fix it and send you a file.  But there are usually enough potential causes for a problem that figuring out the cause requires some investigation.  That's why providing a file would help get your question answered.